# Modular SQL WHERE statement

Tags: python, sql, where-clause, modularity

I'm trying to create prepared SQL statement inside of a python script that has modular inputs. I have the "INSERT" part of the statement working but cannot get the WHERE clause to update modularly. Is there a way to do this?

```
query = "INSERT INTO MachineInfo ( Description, Location, IP, License )
         WHERE id = ID
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"


#The arguments are all predefined variables
args = [ deviceName, deviceLocation, ipAddress, license, ID ]

system.db.runPrepUpdate( query, args )
```

Comment: INSERT has no WHERE clause. (UPDATE has.)

Comment: Could you provide some examples of what your different SQL statements would look like? "cannot get the WHERE clause to update modularly" - I'm not sure what you would like to happen here without more detail.

Comment: Ideally, I want to pass in values from an input to the variables in the "args" line. These inputs are then to be updated in a row in the database where the row updated has the row id that was passed into the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE MachineInfo 
    SET Description = ?,
        Location = ?,
        IP = ?,
        License = ?
    WHERE id = ?;
```